# My output is displayed more than once I want to display it once correcting the below given code

Tags: php, loops

Please help me to rectify my code.
Here I have described the code what and why I am using... and finally whatI am getting at the end, but the end output is not the way what I want... Please help and tell how I can rectify it...

```
$count = substr_count($row4['ACTION_STATEMENT'], " IF (NEW.");/*here i will get how many time i will get " IF (NEW." in my string.*/
                $exp1 = explode("(NEW.",$row4['ACTION_STATEMENT']);/*I exploded it from "NEW."*/
/*echo "<pre>";
print_r($exp1);*/


                for($i=1;$i<count($exp1);$i++)/*Loop for values in $exp1*/
                {
                    //echo $exp1[$i];
                    $exp2[] = explode(" !=",$exp1[$i]);/*exploded by " !="*/
                }//print_r($exp2);

                $flag = true;
                if($flag == true)
                {
                    $column = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '".$row3['TABLE_SCHEMA']."' and TABLE_NAME = '".$row3['TABLE_NAME']."'"); /*This query will give me 21 values*/
                    while ($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($column))
                    {/*echo "<pre>pd";
                    print_r($row5);*/

                        foreach($exp2 as $fieldsarr)/*loop used  for further comaprison of $exp2 with above query values*/
                        { 
                        echo "<br>";

                        //print_r($fieldsarr);

                            if($fieldsarr[0] == $row5['COLUMN_NAME'] )/*Comparison of values*/
                            { 
                                if($fieldsarr[0]!='id')
                                {//echo $fieldsarr[0];

                                mysqli_select_db($link,'pranav_test');
                                $aud = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `jos_menuaudit`") or die("DEAD".mysqli_error());
                                    while($audit = mysqli_fetch_array($aud))
                                    {
                                        echo "<pre>";
                                        echo $fieldsarr[0].$row5['COLUMN_NAME'];
                                    print_r($audit);    /*Values displayed according to query written above after true comparsion of conditions*/
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        mysqli_select_db($link,'information_schema');
                    }
                }
```

Now from above code The output I am getting is

```
namenameArray
(
    [0] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [1] => 0
    [menuid] => 0
    [2] => name
    [field] => name
    [3] => test_PSD_111
    [oldvalue] => test_PSD_111
    [4] => test_SPD_111
    [newvalue] => test_SPD_111
    [5] => 2010-03-24 11:42:26
    [changedone] => 2010-03-24 11:42:26
)

namenameArray
(
    [0] => 2
    [id] => 2
    [1] => 0
    [menuid] => 0
    [2] => name
    [field] => name
    [3] => test_SPD_111
    [oldvalue] => test_SPD_111
    [4] => test_SD_111
    [newvalue] => test_SD_111
    [5] => 2010-03-24 11:44:22
    [changedone] => 2010-03-24 11:44:22
)

namenameArray
(
    [0] => 3
    [id] => 3
    [1] => 0
    [menuid] => 0
    [2] => name
    [field] => name
    [3] => test_SD_111
    [oldvalue] => test_SD_111
    [4] => test_PSD_111
    [newvalue] => test_PSD_111
    [5] => 2010-03-24 11:46:28
    [changedone] => 2010-03-24 11:46:28
)

namenameArray
(
    [0] => 4
    [id] => 4
    [1] => 0
    [menuid] => 0
    [2] => name
    [field] => name
    [3] => test_PSD_111
    [oldvalue] => test_PSD_111
    [4] => test_PD_111
    [newvalue] => test_PD_111
    [5] => 2010-03-24 11:47:30
    [changedone] => 2010-03-24 11:47:30
)

namenameArray
(
    [0] => 5
    [id] => 5
    [1] => 0
    [menuid] => 0
    [2] => name
    [field] => name
    [3] => test_PD_111
    [oldvalue] => test_PD_111
    [4] => test_P_111
    [newvalue] => test_P_111
    [5] => 2010-03-24 11:49:25
    [changedone] => 2010-03-24 11:49:25
)



aliasaliasArray
(
    [0] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [1] => 0
    [menuid] => 0
    [2] => name
    [field] => name
    [3] => test_PSD_111
    [oldvalue] => test_PSD_111
    [4] => test_SPD_111
    [newvalue] => test_SPD_111
    [5] => 2010-03-24 11:42:26
    [changedone] => 2010-03-24 11:42:26
)

aliasaliasArray
(
    [0] => 2
    [id] => 2
    [1] => 0
    [menuid] => 0
    [2] => name
    [field] => name
    [3] => test_SPD_111
    [oldvalue] => test_SPD_111
    [4] => test_SD_111
    [newvalue] => test_SD_111
    [5] => 2010-03-24 11:44:22
    [changedone] => 2010-03-24 11:44:22
)

aliasaliasArray
(
    [0] => 3
    [id] => 3
    [1] => 0
    [menuid] => 0
    [2] => name
    [field] => name
    [3] => test_SD_111
    [oldvalue] => test_SD_111
    [4] => test_PSD_111
    [newvalue] => test_PSD_111
    [5] => 2010-03-24 11:46:28
    [changedone] => 2010-03-24 11:46:28
)

aliasaliasArray
(
    [0] => 4
    [id] => 4
    [1] => 0
    [menuid] => 0
    [2] => name
    [field] => name
    [3] => test_PSD_111
    [oldvalue] => test_PSD_111
    [4] => test_PD_111
    [newvalue] => test_PD_111
    [5] => 2010-03-24 11:47:30
    [changedone] => 2010-03-24 11:47:30
)

aliasaliasArray
(
    [0] => 5
    [id] => 5
    [1] => 0
    [menuid] => 0
    [2] => name
    [field] => name
    [3] => test_PD_111
    [oldvalue] => test_PD_111
    [4] => test_P_111
    [newvalue] => test_P_111
    [5] => 2010-03-24 11:49:25
    [changedone] => 2010-03-24 11:49:25
)
```

thatis, all the five values from query are displayed on every single comaprison getting true. Now here What I want is after the completion of every comparison I want to display the final query result Only Once... hence the End reult should be..

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [id] => 1
    [1] => 0
    [menuid] => 0
    [2] => name
    [field] => name
    [3] => test_PSD_111
    [oldvalue] => test_PSD_111
    [4] => test_SPD_111
    [newvalue] => test_SPD_111
    [5] => 2010-03-24 11:42:26
    [changedone] => 2010-03-24 11:42:26
)

Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [id] => 2
    [1] => 0
    [menuid] => 0
    [2] => name
    [field] => name
    [3] => test_SPD_111
    [oldvalue] => test_SPD_111
    [4] => test_SD_111
    [newvalue] => test_SD_111
    [5] => 2010-03-24 11:44:22
    [changedone] => 2010-03-24 11:44:22
)

Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [id] => 3
    [1] => 0
    [menuid] => 0
    [2] => name
    [field] => name
    [3] => test_SD_111
    [oldvalue] => test_SD_111
    [4] => test_PSD_111
    [newvalue] => test_PSD_111
    [5] => 2010-03-24 11:46:28
    [changedone] => 2010-03-24 11:46:28
)

Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [id] => 4
    [1] => 0
    [menuid] => 0
    [2] => name
    [field] => name
    [3] => test_PSD_111
    [oldvalue] => test_PSD_111
    [4] => test_PD_111
    [newvalue] => test_PD_111
    [5] => 2010-03-24 11:47:30
    [changedone] => 2010-03-24 11:47:30
)

Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [id] => 5
    [1] => 0
    [menuid] => 0
    [2] => name
    [field] => name
    [3] => test_PD_111
    [oldvalue] => test_PD_111
    [4] => test_P_111
    [newvalue] => test_P_111
    [5] => 2010-03-24 11:49:25
    [changedone] => 2010-03-24 11:49:25
)
```

How to accomplish this..Please help....

Comment: Can you make a more clear description of what the end result is supposed to look like?

Comment: Make the title more meaningful, and explain your intent. It is difficult to figure out what you are trying to accomplish with just a wall of code.

Comment: Are you asking how to make it not print "namename"?

Comment: No I a not askin that Anonymous.. please go thru the code and text thoroughly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a limit on the MySQL statement

"SELECT * FROM COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '".$row3['TABLE_SCHEMA']."' and TABLE_NAME = '".$row3['TABLE_NAME']."' LIMIT 1"

then it will only return the one result